# Windows Media Player Playlist (.wlp) - how to save relative paths?

Tags: windows, path, windows-media-player

I'm syncing **Windows Media Player** playlists between computers. Therefore, my playlists need to use **relative paths**, or it will not work on the other computer and vice versa.

Background:

- I'm using [my own batch tool](https://bytecode77.com/coding/scripts/generateplaylists) in order to create playlists from directories. I'm well aware of auto playlists, but they cannot be sorted. My batch tool works, but WMP changes all playlists to absolute paths eventually. I can observe this phenomenon since only recently.
- I'm syncing using Mercurial. *But that's irrelevant, it's just in case someone asks*

**The XML of a playlist**

This is after I sorted the songs and saved it through WMP. However, paths are replaced with absolute paths (starting with D:) later. I can't really tell when this happens.

My destination computer doesn't have a D:\ so same paths is not an option.

```
<?wpl version="1.0"?>
<smil>
    <head>
        <meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Windows Media Player -- 12.0.10586.162"/>
        <meta name="ItemCount" content="6"/>
        <title>Playlist Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <seq>
            <media src="..\......\.....mp3"/>
```

Comment: Set your playlists to readonly?

Comment: Could be an approach, but then I won't be able to sort it manually, either.

Answer (score 1):

WMP also supports playlist of the .m3u type. Do you see the same behavior with that type?

You say that auto playlists cannot be sorted, but are you aware of the `Sort By` condition for auto playlists?

**Edit**: as a workaround to keep the paths same on both computers nevertheless, you could use NTFS junction points or directory symbolic links.

Comment: I tested m3u files and WMP also converts those paths to absolute ones within a couple of hours of using WMP. Also I think auto playlists don't support manual sorting.

Comment: Oh, I thought that you were referring to automatic sorting rather than manual sorting. Auto playlists indeed don't support manual sorting. See the edit of my answer for a workaround.

Comment: I also tried auto playlists and WMP also tampers with the file, removing the path I have specified so no items are displayed. Why does WMP damage my playlists for no reason?

Comment: So the workaround that I suggested isn't an option? Please provide some more details about this auto playlist tampering. Exactly which path does WMP remove?

Comment: I tried to figure out how to create a junction between `D:\Music` and `C:\Users\....\Music`, but it seems like the drive has to exist. Could you elaborate this solution a little more?

Comment: You will need to create a junction on the source computer having the D drive. Remove `D:\Music` from your library locations in WMP. Rename the original `Music` folder in `Users` to something like `Music.old`. Then, in your user folder, run the command `mklink /J Music D:\Music`. If you care about the ratings or play counts in your library, you should probably run [Metadata Backup](https://sourceforge.net/projects/metadatabackup/) first.

Comment: But the `D:` drive has to exist on the other computer, which it doesn't. Therefore and for anyone else reading this, the complete solution should be documented in your answer.

Comment: Why would you still need a D: drive on the destination computer? The point of creating a junction on the source computer is to link `C:\Users\...\Music` to `D:\Music`. That way, WMP would 'see' your music located in `C:\Users\...\Music` while it is in fact still located in `D:\Music`. The result is that the paths on both computers will start with `C:\Users\...\Music`. There's no need for a junction on the destination computer, as the path there is already correct.